# What happens to the motions of a gas if its container is attached to a gyroscopic stabalizer?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, gyroscopes

If you attach a gyroscopic stabilizer to a vehicle like a car, plane, or boat, you stabilize the entire vehicle, effectively increasing the inertia of the vehicle.

My question is, what happens to the internal motions of a gas contained within a tank that is attached to a gyroscopic stabilizer?

This must be a known problem, since, for example, boats have stabilizers, and fuel tanks.

What I'm wondering is, whether a sufficient amount of gyroscopic motion can actually change the behavior of the gas inside a tank.

So as a practical matter, we would forget about the vehicle, and simply study the behavior of a gas contained in a tank attached to a gyroscopic stabilizer. Specifically, I'm curious as to whether this could stabilize the motions of the gas, perhaps making it easier to control, and possibly more efficient to combust.